# NSubstitute to return a Null for an object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I am new to unit testing and it sounds to me like it should be easy to get NSubstitute to be able to return null for a method but I cannot get it to work.

I have tried this for a Get method that should return a Campaign method

```
_campaigns = Substitute.For<IOptions<Campaigns>>();
_campaigns.Get(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(null);
```

In production I use a FirstOrDefault() method to return the campaign object and it returns null if it does not exist. So in my unit test I want to test that case, but I cannot fake it with NSubstitute as I get the following error when compiling:

> error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties: 'SubstituteExtensions.Returns(T, T, params T[])' and
>   'SubstituteExtensions.Returns(T, Func, params
>   Func[])'

I do this to avoid the error:

```
_campaigns.Get(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns((Campaign)null);
```

but then I get an execution error on that line:

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

Comment: Second example must work, I think. Can you show full line where you get `NullReferenceException` -you obviously using return value somehow

Answer (score 25):

In nowdays NSubsitute has method it calls `ReturnsNull` or expression `.Returns(l => null)`
https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/pull/181

Comment: Maybe add to this that we need `using NSubstitute.ReturnsExtensions;` to use `.ReturnsNull`.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and found below solution

```
_campaigns = Substitute.For<IOptions<Campaigns>>();
_campaigns.Get(Arg.Any<string>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(i => null);
```

Also, you can use `.Returns(i => null) or .ReturnsNull()` which return null value for `_campaigns.Get()` method

Comment: Add using  `using NSubstitute.ReturnsExtensions;` to use `ReturnsNull()`

Comment: I found that `ReturnsNull()` does not work if the property type is `bool?`. I get: `The type 'bool?' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ReturnsExtensions.ReturnsNull<T>(T)'`

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem I am using an actual class "Campaigns" and not an Interface, so NSubstitute was using the actual class :(

NSubstitute is design to work with interfaces.

So instead of using NSubstitute in this case I have just created a fake object for my class.